# Few small blogposts vs one big blogpost

Tags: seo, wordpress, blog, ranking

I have a blog about different Internet and programming topics, and a few posts which have rather good ranking and some traffic.

One blog post is about a tool I developed. I make updates to the tool, so now comes the question:

Is it better to make a new small blog post containing information about the updates, OR is it better to edit the first bigger post? Which way would rank better or produce more traffic?

Answer (score 1):

As supported by the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13931659/seo-results-from-a-single-blog-vs-multiple-blogs), since the blog post(s) is about one tool, adding to a single blog post would increase the content and keywords for that blog post, and thus relevancy for search engines, which is an important factor in ranking.

That would also allow you to focus your editorial efforts, marketing, and inbound links on one page/URL versus many.

Comment: No problem - Dan from USA :-)